# How to create Stream Provider in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I've done many searches and nothing helped to get rid of the error.

here is my code :

**main.dart**

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the auth services where I created the stream:

**auth.dart**

```dart
  // Create user object based on fireBase user
  User _userFromFireBaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }


  // Auth change stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
    .map(_userFromFireBaseUser);
  }
```

And finally here is how I add it in my `Wrapper`:

**Wrapper.dart**

```dart
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    final loggedUser = Provider.of<User>(context);
   print(loggedUser);
    return Authenticate();
  }
}
```

it returns this error :

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this Wrapper Widget

To fix, please:

  * Ensure the Provider<User> is an ancestor to this Wrapper Widget
  * Provide types to Provider<User>
  * Provide types to Consumer<User>
  * Provide types to Provider.of<User>()
  * Ensure the correct `context` is being used.
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the StreamProvider one level up into runApp method?

Comment: @FederickJonathan same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling directly Wrapper class.

```
runApp(Wrapper());
```

Instead do

```
runApp(MyApp());
```

Comment: Tried and got the same error .. also as I know using  `return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;` gives the same as your code

Comment: i am following same tutorial and when i replace your code with mine then i got the same error. i am also in dilemma, how it is happening.

Comment: did you try full restart ? @AhmedWagdi

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I've even uninstalled the app then reinstalled it. same result!

Comment: it is really silly to ask but, your _auth variable is in auth.dart and   final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; ?

Comment: What tutorial if I may ask?

Comment: Flutter firebase authentication tutorial by net ninja https://github.com/iamshaunjp/flutter-firebase